# Reload/cancel partial view within main page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

With in my main page, i have a hidden div which i load a partial view contains a form into it.

**Main view**

```
 <div id="partial_load" style="display: none;">

</div>
```

**Script**

```
$('#initCreatePro').click(function () {
var id = $(this).data('assigned-id');
$('#partial_load').show();
$('#partial_load').load('/User/CreatePartial?userid=' + id);
});
```

So far so good, now within my partial view i have a form with 3 buttons

1. Submit==> OK no issue
2. Cancel==> I want to cancel and hide back div or unload the partial view
3. Next ==> when clicked, it navigates to an action which will modify the data and should reload the partial view with modified data

**Within Partial view**

```
<button class="btn" type="button">Cancel</button>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Next", "User", Model)" class="btn btn-success">Next</a>
        <input id="subButon" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" style=" right: 15px;" />
```

**Next action**

```
public ActionResult Next(UserViewModel uvm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Uow.Users.Add(uvm.User);
            Uow.Commit();

            uvm.User.RecalculateScore();
            return PartialView("_Create", uvm);


        }
    }
```

How can i force the partial view in the hidden div to be reloaded with the new data when next is clicked, also how can i rest the form and hide the div when cancel is clicked

Comment: You should be making use of jquery ajax !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 'Cancel' button, change the html to

```
<button id="cancel" class="btn" type="button">Cancel</button>// add id attribute
```

and in the main view add the following script

```
$('#partial_load').on('click', '#cancel', function() {
    $('#partial_load').empty();
});
```

Side note: There is no real need to include `style="display: none;` in your `<div id="partial_load">` element and you can also delete `$('#partial_load').show();` on your script.

For your 'Next' button, its a bit unclear what you trying to do. Your current code is doing a redirect to your controllers `Next()` method and passing the original unchanged model, and if your `UserViewModel` model contains any properties which are complex objects (which property `User` appears to be) or collections, binding will fail. If if binding does succeed and you get a valid `UserViewModel` object, your `RecalculateScore()` method suggests you changing the values of properties in the model, but because your model has already been added to `ModelState`, those changes will not be reflected in the view.

Assuming you want to submit the edited values in the form to a method which saves it and returns a different view then your code should be

```
<button id="next" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Next</button>

$('#partial_load').on('click', '#next', function() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("Next", "User")';
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    $.post(url, form.serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#partial_load').html(data);
    });
});
```

Where your method is a POST

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Next(UserViewModel uvm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ....
        ModelState.Clear();
        return PartialView("_Create", uvm);
    }
    else
    {
        // return the same partial view so that validation errors are displayed
    }
}
```

Side note: Its not clear what your `RecalculateScore()` method is doing, but it may be easier to use `return Json(someValues);` and update the existing partial with the new values.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. i will try your solution and also i will try to edit my post and make it more clear (Sorry my english is limited)

Comment: the cancel button works great thx alot, the Next button when i click, i can see that the click event is triggered however the redirection to the url never happens and it doesn't arrive to the action Next.

Comment: what do you mean redirection? You question states _should reload the partial view with modified data_ which means stay in the same page, not redirect. As I noted, its hard to understand what it is your trying to do when you click the 'Next' button. The code I have shown will hit the `Next()` action method and return a partial view to update the DOM. If its not, debug your code and inspect the browser console for errors.

Comment: ,Ok, sorry to use the Redirect, ok, in my case the code is not hitting the next() but i will do as you said and i will debug again. and regarding what the functionality of the next() function. here is the scenario:  the user will click a button which will load the partial view inside the div, then fill in the form, then click next, when next is clicked, the data will be saved in the database and the user should be able to continue adding another record and the partial view should remain displayed.

Comment: OK, That's exactly what the code in my answer will do. If its not hitting the method, then you have some errors. Start by checking the browser console and see what errors are displayed.